# Trying to compare dates, getValues() converts date into string. Can't compare

Tags: date, comparison, google-sheets

Using Google Forms and Sheets, I am trying to set up a simple booking system where I need to find matches for a particular date and display the booking data. The problem I am having is that when I pull the booking dates from the spreadsheet, they seem to be converted into strings, so I can no longer compare them easily.

My Code:

```
//The is the handler for the date-picker
function dateChange(eventInfo) {

var selectedDate = eventInfo.parameter.date_picker;
var bookingsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var bookingsDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<ID IN HERE>");

//Get data for current event
var bookingsData = bookingsDatabase.getSheetByName('<SHEET>');

//Get data for selected date
var bookingsDatesList = bookingsData.getRange(2,2,bookingsData.getLastRow()).getValues();

//This pops up with 'Sat Dec 27 2014 03:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) - Sat Dec 27 2014 03:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' - They echo the same, but they don't generate matches.
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(bookingsDatesList[0] + " - " + selectedDate);

//This pops up with 'Sat Dec 27 2014 03:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) - 1419678000000' - the date on the left doesn't seem to be a date object because it doesn't convert to an integer.
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(bookingsDatesList[0].valueOf() + " - " + selectedDate.valueOf());

// Search for selected date among database entries
for(var n=0; n<bookingsDatesList.length-1; n++) {
  if(bookingsDatesList[n].valueOf() == selectedDate.valueOf()) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('match!');
  }
}
```

Is my only option here to try and reconvert each string back into a date? Or can I convert the date-picker date into a string also? Or is it option 3 - I'm missing something really obvious here.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: In continuing to play around I tried getting just one value instead of a whole bunch of values - when I do this, the data remains a date object - it works. Why should the results be different between getValue and getValues?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've used my above revelation to try a different approach, using getValue() instead of getValues() and it works fine. Changed the code as follows:

```
var bookingsDatesList = bookingsData.getRange(2,2,bookingsData.getLastRow());

// Search for selected date among database entries
for(var n=1; n<bookingsDatesList.getNumRows(); n++) {
  if(bookingsDatesList.getCell(n,1).getValue().valueOf() == selectedDate.valueOf()) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('match!');
  }
}
```

Like this it the match alerts pop up just fine. Very weird that I have to use single 'getValue()' commands rather than 'getValues()'.